# Qt remove title bar from all widget and dialog in application

Tags: qt

I know how to remove title bar from widget or QDialog, But I want to know is there any way to omit the title bar from all of the widget in application with single code,like `QApplication.setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);` (for example)

Comment: You can subclass all things you need to set this flag themselves and only use the subclasses?

Comment: how? could you explain it plz?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm

Comment: @MaxGo you mean I create base dialog and base class for all of my widget and they inheritance to them?Is there another way with coding?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what @rubenvb suggested above. I don't think that another way exists. Qt should provide this way through it's API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually I'm in need to do so, I usually do it with

> Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint

It should be used in the very top of your main function so you should end with something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  WindowName window;

  window.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  window.show();
}
```

Comment: It does not work. the QDialog show the title bar. I want to apply this code for all widget, Is there any way?

Comment: @H.Ghassami try this when declaring your qdialog dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

Comment: @H.Ghassami I'm sorry then I don't know of the existence of such global setting